# Vue TypeScript uses vue-property-decorator to prompt that router-view is not registered

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

If I execute the code above, I will get an error after running.

```
Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

If I remove

```
@Component
```

Can I use it normally.

how can I use @Component correctly?

---

I have already registered my route in main.ts when I remove @Component. The router-view is in effect.

====

Used on every page

```
Import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

This is effective!

Comment: Did you call `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'; ... Vue.use(VueRouter);` somewhere in your app?

Comment: Like @FK82 said. You need to import the router into your vue instance. Useally in a `main.ts` file.